# EXC_BAD_ACCESS after reopening app with Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, exc-bad-access, persistent-storage

I have an app that uses Core Data.  I'm able to save and fetch data upon the first time my app builds and runs in the simulator, however, when I close the app, kill it in the simulator, and re-run it, it crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` inside of main.

If I uninstall the app on the simulator and run it again, every thing works fine again, until I close the app and open it again when the same thing happens.

This never used to happen before adding Core Data to my app so I'm assuming it has something to do with that.  Below is a backtrace after the crash.

Is it possible I'm not properly "closing" my persistent store after killing the app?
Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

```
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x01700df5 in objc_release ()
#1  0x01701c60 in (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop ()
#2  0x01490ed8 in _CFAutoreleasePoolPop ()
#3  0x00e959f9 in -[NSAutoreleasePool release] ()
#4  0x005a4f78 in _UIApplicationHandleEvent ()
#5  0x02154fa9 in PurpleEventCallback ()
#6  0x015301c5 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#7  0x01495022 in __CFRunLoopDoSource1 ()
#8  0x0149390a in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#9  0x01492db4 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#10 0x01492ccb in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#11 0x005a12a7 in -[UIApplication _run] ()
#12 0x005a2a9b in UIApplicationMain ()
#13 0x00001f29 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbfffebc4) at main.m:14
#14 0x00001ea5 in start ()
```

**Update**
Enabled Zombie objects and exception logging

```
2012-02-12 14:13:06.162 App[75491:207] *** -[_PFArray release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6d71960
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x014c2ce2 in __forwarding_prep_0___ ()
#1  0x01700e10 in objc_release ()
#2  0x01701c60 in (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop ()
#3  0x01490ed8 in _CFAutoreleasePoolPop ()
#4  0x00e959f9 in -[NSAutoreleasePool release] ()
#5  0x005a4f78 in _UIApplicationHandleEvent ()
#6  0x02154fa9 in PurpleEventCallback ()
#7  0x015301c5 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#8  0x01495022 in __CFRunLoopDoSource1 ()
#9  0x0149390a in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#10 0x01492db4 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#11 0x01492ccb in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#12 0x005a12a7 in -[UIApplication _run] ()
#13 0x005a2a9b in UIApplicationMain ()
#14 0x00001f29 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbfffeb64) at main.m:14
#15 0x00001ea5 in start ()
```

Comment: Can you enable zombie objects in the scheme settings and then recreate the crash? You should get more information about the object that's being over-released.

Comment: I actually didn't get much more information than before.  I've added the backtrace above.  Is there another gdb command I can run to give me more information.

Comment: Ok, try profiling the app in Instruments using the 'Zombies' template. You can get much more information about where that object was created and used.

Comment: Thank you that helped a lot.  I found out what my error was.  I was releasing an object that was being auto release as well. Here was the culprit code:
NSMutableArray *objects = [[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
...
[objects release];